# lQuery mobile breaks select fieldset on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an app built with phonegap and jQuery mobile. On android everything is fine, but on iOS 6, some elements are acting weird.

Screenshot:
[image]
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you developing for iOS6? It's just about 2% of people who still have that version.

Comment: Please show your code and maybe even create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue.